# Tabindex is not working for <a> tag inside fieldset in HTML

Tags: html

I have designed a HTML for with the tabindex set to the fieds. There are 3 fieldsets. The lower fieldset contains the submit  tab with the proper tabindex specified. But the tab is not pointing to the  tag. After fieldset2 it is moving directly to fieldset.

Please find the following code described:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="registrationfrm">
            <fieldset id="personalinfo">
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_firstname">first name</label> 
                <div class="inputwrapper">    
                    <input type="text" tabindex="201" value="" name="register_firstname" id="register_firstname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_lastname">last name</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="202" name="register_lastname" id="register_lastname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_industry">industry</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">

<select  tabindex="203" id="register_industry" name="register$industry">
<option value="">--- please select an industry ---</option>
<option value="adagency">Ad Agency/Public Relations</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
            </div>        
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_role">role</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <select tabindex="204" id="register_role" name="register_role">
<option value="">--- please select a role ---</option>
<option value="Education">Educator/Student</option>
<option value="MktSales">Marketing/Sales</option>
</select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>      
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_loginname">user name</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="205" name="register_loginname" id="register_loginname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_emailaddress">email address</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="206" name="register_emailaddress" id="register_emailaddress">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_password">password</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="password" value="" tabindex="207" name="register_password" id="register_password">
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_passwordconfirm">confirm password</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="password" tabindex="208" value="" name="register_passwordconfirm" id="register_passwordconfirm">
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_securityquestion">security question</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
<select tabindex="209" id="register_securityquestion" name="register$securityquestion">
<option value="">--- please select a question ---</option>
<option value="School">What was the name of your elementary school?</option>
</select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fieldwrapper">
                <label for="register_securityanswer">security answer</label>
                <div class="inputwrapper">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="210" title="security answer" value="" name="register_securityanswer" id="register_securityanswer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="registrationcheckboxes">
            <label for="register_agree"><input type="checkbox" name="register_agree" id="register_agree" class="checkbox {validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'Please review and accept the terms and conditions. If you do not agree to the terms and conditions please use the website as our guest.'}}}" tabindex="211" value="true">&nbsp;I accept Neenah's terms and conditions.</label>
            <div id="register_agreetoterms_exception"></div>
            <label for="register_receiveemails"><input type="checkbox" checked="" name="register_receiveemails" id="register_receiveemails" tabindex="212" value="true">&nbsp;YES, I would like to receive occassional emails about Neenah Paper news and special offers.</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="submitsection">
                <a tabindex="213" id="registration_submit" href="#">register account</a>
        </fieldset>
            </form>
```

### CSS

```
#registration .fieldwrapper {
display:inline;
float:left;
padding:0 3px;
}


.inputwrapper {
display:block;
font-size:12px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}


a#registration_submit {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:transparent url(/images/global/CreateNewAccountSubmit.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
float:left;
height:21px;
position:relative;
text-indent:-9000px;
width:160px;
}
```

I would be very glad to have your sugestion.

Thanks,
Nirmal

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what the problem is.  Using your supplied HTML + CSS, tabbing appears to be working correctly.  The tab order is from the top to the bottom, with the submit link being the last element on the page to receive tab focus. You are using an `a` link tag for your form submission, which is unusual, and your CSS is hiding the link, but the tab order works as expected. Please can you explain in more detail what you want to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: Why are you using TabIndex in this case (unless you're using a wrapper that has tabindexes)? The form items are in the natural flow and your specified tabindexes doesn't bring anything additional to the page.

Comment: Mike, I want the focus on <a tabindex="213" id="registration_submit" href="#">register account</a> has to be display on the screen. Now when I am pressing tab in register_receiveemails checkbox the focus directly moving to the FirstName textbox in the popup. 
Rather this should be done in following way
register_receiveemails checkbox->TAB->SUBMIT BUTTON->TAB->FIRSTNAME

Comment: One more information, If I am instering a textbox or button in the last fieldset with a tabindex of 214. Then I can able to see the focus on the submit link, then the inserted textbox or button and then firstname textbox.

Comment: Gert,
This coding is a part of modal popup window being displayed using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, and it does give focus to the registration link. But the registration link isn't shown due to the text indentation being set to `-9000px`. In order to do so, you can use the focus pseudo class and remove the text indentation. E.g.

```
a#registration_submit:focus {
    text-indent:0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't work in the older IE browsers. To fix that, you might have to resort to JavaScript.